# Отмена ТОЛЬКО действий браузера по умолчанию

Tags: javascript

Имеется текстовое поле `contenteditalbe`.

Я отменяю все действия браузера, которые по умолчанию, через событие `onkeydown` и методом `preventDefault()` объекта `event`.

Все работает как подобает, но в таком случае не срабатывает событие `onkeypress`, с помощью которого я хочу получить код символа и вставить в поле при помощи `fromCharCode`.

То-есть, событие `onkeydown` отменяет вместе с действиями браузера по умолчанию и событие `onkeypress`.

Как справиться с этим недугом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давай те вначале разберемся с событиями и их порядком:

*onkeydown* - cрабатывает в момент нажатия клавиши, но когда она еще не отпущена
*onkeypress* - срабатывает, когда клавиша на клавиатуре нажата и отпущена
*onkeyup* - срабатывает в момент отпускания нажатой клавиши

Вообще *onkeypress* - это эквивалент срабатыванию *onkeydown* -> *onkeyup*.
И порядок срабатывания событий таков: *onkeydown* -> *onkeypress* -> *onkeyup*.
Можно воспользоваться *onkeypress* и в обработчике возвращать false, тогда вывод символа не произойдет.

Comment: Вы немного напутали. `onkeydown` получает через событие скан код символа, а `onkeypress` код символа и на данный момент, в современных браузерах `onkeypress` срабатывает при нажатии и удерживании клавиши, а не при отпускании. И события браузера происходит раньше чем событие `onkeypress` следовательно одного `onkeypress` недостаточно для данной процедуры.

Comment: Все верно, onkeypress не срабатывает при отпускании, я не верно написал. Я не могу понять, чем вас не устрайвает событие keypress? Как до события keypress, так и после return false; внутри обработчика keypress ничего не вставляется в поле http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqBrxX

Comment: То-есть, перейдя по ссылке пример я должен попытаться напечатать что-то в поле Input и туда ничего не будет добавлено? Печатаю и символы прекрасно добавляются. Браузер хром последний и мозила тоже последняя

Comment: Ну вообще в примере символы добавляются посредством fromCharCode, вы на код посмотрите! Так же после ввода курсор перемещается в конец.

Comment: Пардон))) Я облажался. Там у меня код немного запутан, теперь я правильно ретурны прописал. Да, оказывается что keypress срабатывает раньше чем действия браузера по умолчанию.